# Slider not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Please take a look at this: http://nichemarketingreviews.nl/

In IE9 all of a sudden the slider is not working anymore. I did not do anything on the code of the site, only made some posts in the backend of WP.

Can anyone see or tell me what is going wrong?
Would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code of that site here? Or alternatively, use jsfiddle or some other platform. Otherwise, this question will be quite useless for future visitors

Comment: Slider? Do you mean scroll-bar?

Comment: "all of a sudden"? After a few days/weeks? Both IE9 and jQuery have been updated in the past few days. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/08/14/ie-9-0-9-available-via-windows-update.aspx and http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/

Comment: I'm with @Speed - I've had issues in the past with Nivoslider and whatever the latest version of jQuery is.  I'd try downgrading the version you are pulling in to see if that sorts it.

Comment: @Speed I havent updated jquery. I tried downgrading it now, does not help. All of a sudden really means all of a sudden. Just noticed it whilst i did not make any changes. there is a likewise site running at www.koksgilde.nl which works just fine with IE9. So we can outrule that IE9 is the problem. 

Only thing i did was add some new posts in wordpress.

Comment: @LukasEder I do not know which part of the code i should paste since I am looking for a needle in a haystack :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sofar the only answer to make the nivo slider work again in IE9 is by parsing it as IE8.
add this to the head of your file (before )

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

I do not really like the answer since the problem actually still excists for IE9, though it works.
If somebody has a better work around, i will be gladd to see your better answer